# How to draw triangle with transparent background with border?

Tags: css

I would like to know how to draw a triangle with a transparent background with borders? The examples I had found do not provide borders. Any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KCLjH/)

```
 .triangle {
     width: 0;
     height: 0;
     border-left: 50px solid transparent;
     border-right: 50px solid transparent;
     border-bottom: 100px solid red;
     position:relative;
 }
 .triangle:after{
     content:'';
     position:absolute;
     top:5px;
     left:-45px;
     width: 0;
     height: 0;
     border-left: 45px solid transparent;
     border-right: 45px solid transparent;
     border-bottom: 92px solid white;
}
```

Comment: This is not transparent, its a white background

Comment: this is not the answer, this is a triangle with white background, not transparent

Answer (score 13):

Here's a transparent pure css triangle with borders:

```
.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    border-top: 4px solid #e74c3c;
}

.triangle {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: -70px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 137px;
    height: 137px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    border-right: 4px solid #e74c3c;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #e74c3c;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pmq69/1/)

Comment: For someone looking for a solution this is the WORST demo I've ever seen.

Comment: Since I am using most of css3 features in the tool I am building, this is actually usable and better than using a image or canvas.

Comment: @MichalSzyndel just because you couldn't understand css3 transforms you called it the Worst demo? I mean come on. That's too negative bro!

Comment: @NaveedAhmad it's way too fancy and cluttered, it is confusing instead of clarifying.

Answer (score -1):

It triangle with a transparent background, borders you can do using two of these one above the other
http://jsfiddle.net/alexdets/vYAZQ/26/

Answer (score -2):

Absolutely position a slightly smaller triangle on an existing one.