# css3 triangle without background color

Tags: html, css, colors, background

I want to create a triangle with css3. I found many example about triangles. But all of them has a background color. How can i do that without background color?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that what you need is a triangle that has only the border in a certain color, the rest being transparent (or white, whichever).

Based on the CSS3 border-width and border-color properties I'm guessing that it's not possible to get what you need. Basically because the borders which are drawn at an angle by the browser have well-defined drawing modes and none resemble what you need.

What you could try is border-image property in CSS3, but basically that's more-or-less equivalent with placing an image (or some div with that image as background-image) on the page.

Comment: thank you for your message. I've found the solution here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264110/how-to-draw-triangle-with-transparent-background-with-border

Comment: Yes, I've thought of that solution, but doesn't seem to be very helpful when the interior of the triangle needs to be transparent.

Comment: my interior of triangle must be white. So it is useful for me.